# Перезаписать элементы таблицы по массиву

Tags: php, mysql

Я записываю данные таблицы из mysql с помощью pdo в один массив, изменяю его (могу удалить строку, добавить, изменить), а после этого мне необходимо записать его снова в бд. Я пока вижу только вариант в виде цикла с проверкой, изменен ли элемент массива, если да, то перезаписывать. Но тогда и при удалении одного элемента все сместится и будет перезаписано, что не критично, конечно, но мне кажется, должен быть способ лучше. Можно ли сделать как-то проще?

Comment: Не производите модификацию массива на прямую, создайте одну функцию (или несколько, вроде insert/update/delete), которая будет это делать. При этом такая функция должна помечать измененные записи и сохранять в другой массив id удаленных. когда придет время писать в БД вы просто пройдетесь по записям на которых стоят флаги изменения и только их проведете в БД. P.S. И никакая сдвижка в массиве мешать не должна, ведь работа с БД должна идти на основе id записей, а не их позиции в массиве